# Unexpected value 'AppAsideModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add an @NgModule annotation

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, typescript, angular-material

I have try to upgrade my project the version angular13 to angular17, that time I got "Unexpected value 'AppAsideModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add an @NgModule annotation." error. any idea how to resolve it.

```
enter code here

import {
  AppAsideModule,
  AppBreadcrumbModule,
  AppFooterModule,
  AppHeaderModule,
  AppSidebarModule,
} from "@coreui/angular";


 @NgModule({
   imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   AppRoutingModule,
   AppAsideModule,
   KeycloakAngularModule,
   AppBreadcrumbModule.forRoot(),
   AppFooterModule,
   AppHeaderModule,
   AppSidebarModule,
   BrowserAnimationsModule,
   FormsModule,
   ReactiveFormsModule,
   HttpClientModule,
   NgxCaptchaModule,
   SharedModule,
   DropdownModule,
   DialogModule,
   CardModule,
   MenubarModule,
   SidebarModule,
   AutoCompleteModule
  ],
 declarations: [],
 providers: [],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: please share the code, if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated!

Answer (score 0):

There is no `AppAsideModule` in the [`source code of coreui-angular`](https://github.com/coreui/coreui-angular/blob/main/projects/coreui-angular/src/public-api.ts) maybe it got removed, try removing this import and check if the application runs, you also need to revisit `aside` implementation in your project to check if it still works, but this will get rid of the error, hopefully the app will compile!